# how to zip the contents of a folder using commnad line argument?

Tags: ant, cmd

How can i zip the contents of a folder using command line argument.
I dont prefer to use 3rd party batch file.

I have a folder named "folder1" conmprising of folders 1,2,3,...
I want to zip the contents into folder1.zip file.
If i zip the folder1 , the zip file contains from folder1 .
i.e, the zip file when extracted will have folder1/folder1/(contents of the folder)
I just need to get the contents of the folder1 in the zip file.
i.e, the zip file when extracted should have folder1/(contents).
i would be happy if i can the solution in form of an ant target.

Wating for reply .

Thanks in advance.
Sachin.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Why don't you simply use the [ant `<zip>` task](http://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/zip.html) for that:

```
<zip destfile="${dist}/manual.zip">
  <zipfileset dir="folder1/folder1" prefix="folder1"/>
  <zipfileset dir="folder1/folder2" prefix="folder1"/>
  <zipfileset dir="folder1/folder3" prefix="folder1"/>
</zip>
```

This will zip the contents of the `folder1/folder[1-3]` directories into the directory `folder1` in the `example.zip` file.

EDIT: Updated to reflect the changes to the question.

Answer (score 1):

How about using the [zip ant task](http://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/zip.html)?

```
<zip destfile="folder1.zip" basedir="folder1" />
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also use [`exec`](http://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/exec.html) task.

```
<property name="folder" value="folder1"/>

<target name="zip">
    <exec dir="${pathToFolder}${folder}" executable="cmd.exe">
        <arg line="/c zip arch -rq *.*"/>
        </exec>
</target>
```